# Does not show multiple notifications

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have an edit box, where the user can specify links (comma separated) to download. My requirement is that for each download a separate notification must appear. In my current code, the problem is that i am not able to show multiple notifications at once. They are appearing sequentially, i.e once a download completes only then another notification appears. I tried a lot of things, but nothing seems to work for me. Any suggestions related to this is highly appreciated.

Code:

```
class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        private String filePath;
        private Context mdcontext;
        private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;
        NotificationManager nManager;
        Notification notif;
        android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
        int Id;

        Notification not;

        public DownloadTask(Context context, int id) {
            mdcontext = context;
            this.Id = id;

            nManager = (NotificationManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
            mBuilder.setContentTitle("Download")
                    .setContentText("Download in progress")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            mBuilder.setProgress(0, 0, true);
            notif = mBuilder.build();

            notif.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            Log.i("NotificationCreator", "building notification");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
            InputStream input = null;
            OutputStream output = null;
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            String apkNames = sUrl[0];

            String files[] = apkNames.split("/");
            String apkName = files[files.length - 1];

            try {

                URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                // expect HTTP 200 OK, so we don't mistakenly save error report
                // instead of the file
                if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    return "Server returned HTTP "
                            + connection.getResponseCode() + " "
                            + connection.getResponseMessage();
                }

                // this will be useful to display download percentage
                // might be -1: server did not report the length
                int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

                // download the file
                input = connection.getInputStream();
                // try this
                if (!Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment
                        .getExternalStorageState())) {

                    filePath = context.getFilesDir() + "/" + apkName;
                    output = new FileOutputStream(filePath);

                } else {
                    filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                            + apkName;
                    output = new FileOutputStream(filePath);

                }

                byte data[] = new byte[4096];
                int total = 0;
                int count;
                synchronized (nManager) {
                    nManager.notify(Id, notif);
                }
                Log.i("Installer", "Showing notification");
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    // allow canceling with back button
                    if (isCancelled()) {
                        input.close();
                        return null;
                    }
                    total += count;
                    if (fileLength > 0)
                        output.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                SharedPreferences manag = context.getSharedPreferences(
                        "Paths file", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                Editor edt = manag.edit();
                edt.putString("apk path 1", filePath);
                edt.commit();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (output != null)
                        output.close();
                    if (input != null)
                        input.close();
                } catch (IOException ignored) {

                }

                if (connection != null)
                    connection.disconnect();
            }

            return filePath;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // take CPU lock to prevent CPU from going off if the user
            // presses the power button during download
            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
                    getClass().getName());
            mWakeLock.acquire();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            mWakeLock.release();
            if (result == null) {
                nManager.cancel(Id);
            } else {
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(result));
                try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
                    intent.setDataAndType(uri,
                            "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                    nManager.cancel(Id);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    nManager.cancel(Id);
                    Log.e("Installer ", e.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: means you want to show all the notification at a time?? If you want like this way then you must need to show notification after all the images downloaded completely.

Comment: yes i mean, separate thread for each download, each notification for each download

Comment: hmm ok, then right now whats is showing?

Comment: it is showing one after another

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54970/discussion-about-images-downloading can you please join this chat room

Comment: Need to discuss proper on this, otherwise hard to find solution

Comment: are you there??? or again away

Comment: On which android version are you testing? On newer versions the `AsyncTasks` run sequentially so the the `NotificationManager` can't post the new notifications because new tasks are queued(run one by one). Try using the `executeOnExecutor()` method instead of `execute()`. Also, use the `publishProgress()` instead of the synchronized block(to post the notification) and I hope you don't plan to start a lot of `AsyncTasks`(which will trash the smoothness of the UI, and the reason why AsyncTask run sequentially).

Comment: yeah, i read about it sometime ago. they work in some sort of sequence. Thanks for the time though @Luksprog

Comment: @Abby I think Luksprog's reply is good and may be it will work for you as well, just try like that way dear

Comment: @Abby have you done with this?

Comment: @pratik, i appreciate your concern, but this is not a social networking site! So lets just limit our communication to exchanging solutions.

Comment: @Abby okie, I also appreciate your concern of replying, but as per my knowledge I have not sent you any kind of social kind of messages here, was jus asking that you have solved or not and that;s it. So you just need to think twice before post comment.

Comment: @pratik, i didn't mean to offend you. other stackmates have never pinged me on chat multiple times . so i thought may be you are mistaken. again i am sorry, if i offended you.

Comment: @Abby its not the proper way to talk with anyone who didnt made any mistake to you, is I have asked you any bad words in chat so you talking me like this way